# C++ : segmentation Fault

Tags: c++

**My C++ code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std ;

struct Node {
    int data ;
    struct Node* next;
};

Node* Insert(Node *head,int data);

int main(){
    struct Node* head = NULL;
    struct Node* second = NULL;
    struct Node* third = NULL;
    head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    second = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    third = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    head->data = 7;
    head->next = second;
    second->data = 17;
    second->next = third;
    third->data = 37;
    third->next = NULL;

    head = Insert(head,3);
}
Node* Insert(Node *head,int data)
{
  while (true)
    {   cout << "hey" ;
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            cout << "hey";
            head->data = data ;
            head->next = NULL ;
            break ;
        }
        head = head->next ;
    }

    return head;
}
```

I am tring to learning Linked List in C++. 
I am passing a head and data to insert in the node using `Insert()` function that i have defined.

**My output to terminal**

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I think i am invocating `Insert()` function in a wrong way.
Please Help ! 
Thanks !

Comment: debug it step by step with a debugger and you'll know what's going wrong.

Comment: Don't use malloc in C++ code. Use the new operator. Don't use "using namespace std" and learn to use a debugger instead of placing print statements everywhere.

Comment: I tried adding `cout` in the first line right below main function. 
It didn't print anything.
Problem is at runtime iself

Comment: @LukeG   the `malloc()`  was working without Insert function beign invocated. So the problem is not `malloc` .

Comment: @VivekIyer That's not what I'm saying. Aside from your current problem you should not use malloc in C++ code, because there are better alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing out that `head` is `NULL` when it enters you if statement.

This should fix it:

```
Node* Insert(Node *head,int data) {
  while (head != NULL) {
        if (head->next == NULL) {
            struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            newNode->data = data ;
            newNode->next = NULL ;
            head->next = newNode;
            head = newNode;
            break ;
        }
        head = head->next ;
    }

    return head;
}
```

Comment: Note that this does not create a new List when you try to insert a value on an empty list (i.e. NULL), but returns NULL in that case. You should check if that is the desired behavior

Comment: good point @LukeG but it doesn't make sense to write `Insert(NULL, 4);`. Because how can you insert to NULL?

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in this part of your code:

```
if (head == NULL)
{
    cout << "hey";
    head->data = data ;
    head->next = NULL ;
    break ;
}
```

First you check if head is NULL, and if head is NULL you try to dereference (`head->data`) the head pointer, which is undefined behaviour and leads to a segfault in your case.

I propose the following algorithm:

```
if(head == NULL) {
    Node* newHead = new Node();
    newHead->data = data;
    newHead->next = NULL;
    return newHead;
}
while(head->next != NULL) head = head->next;
head->next = new Node();
head->next->data = data;
head->next->next = NULL;
return head;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong here:

```
if (head == NULL)
{
    cout << "hey";
    head->data = data ;
    head->next = NULL ;
    break ;
}
```

If `head` is `NULL`, so you can't assign `data` to its `head->data`. This causes SIGSEGV.